# Crash in NSDateformatter setDateFormat method

Tags: ios

```
-(NSString*) convertToDateString:(NSString*)str{

    static NSDateFormatter *InDateFormatter = nil;
    static NSDateFormatter *OutDateFormatter = nil;
    NSString *outDate = nil;

    if([str isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [str length] > 0){
    NSString *dateStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:str];
        if (InDateFormatter == nil) {

            InDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            InDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
        }
        if (OutDateFormatter == nil) {

            OutDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            OutDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yy";
        }
        NSRange rangeOfDash = [dateStr rangeOfString:@"T"];
        dateStr = (rangeOfDash.location != NSNotFound) ? [dateStr substringToIndex:rangeOfDash.location] : dateStr;

        if([dateStr isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [dateStr length] == 10){
NSDate* date = [InDateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr];
            if (date != nil) {
                outDate = [OutDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

            }
        }
    }

        return outDate;
}
```

Crash occurred in the line "InDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd"; 
 There will be multiple instances of class that gets created in parallel and invokes the above method. Crash is rarely reproducible.

Am I not using the date formatter correctly?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your code multithreaded?

Comment: BTW - there is no line of code referencing a variable named `auctionInDateFormatter` in the code you posted.

Comment: 0  CoreFoundation  -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 541
1  CoreFoundation  -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 414
2  Foundation  -[NSDateFormatter setDateFormat:] + 86
3  Model.m line 47   -[Model convertToDateString:]

Comment: Code is multithreaded.

Comment: crash occurred in line InDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html): "`NSDateFormatter` is not thread safe, so you must not mutate a given date formatter simultaneously from multiple threads."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a thread-safe lazy initialization, you can use the GCD `dispatch_once()`
function:

```
static NSDateFormatter *inDateFormatter;
static NSDateFormatter *outDateFormatter;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    inDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    inDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
    outDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    outDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yy";
});
```

Comment: Replaced the date formatter creation code as mentioned above. It is working fine now.